# SSL Error when Repository import from Bitbucket

Tags: git, gitlab, ssl-certificate, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I have been installed gitlab and I was trying to import Bitbucket repos to gitlab. But my Bitbucket has a self-signed certificate. I have installed that Bitbucket public certificate to gitlab server using  `update-ca-trust`. Still, I am getting this error when I try to import repos from Bitbucket to gitlab.

> Unable to connect to server: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0
> state=error: certificate verify failed (self signed certificate in
> certificate chain)

Do you have an idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I too am interested in this

Comment: I would also like to know if someone found a solution.